# Strange issue with Python class inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes

I'm getting an issue with class inheritance in Python that I can't seem to make sense of. It may just be my inexperience with Python.

I was able to replicate the issue with this example (I'm using Python 3.3.4):

```
class R(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self._R = [x, y, w, h]

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._R[0]
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._R[0] = value
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._R[1]
    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._R[1] = value
    @property
    def width(self):
        return self._R[2]
    @width.setter
    def width(self, value):
        self._R[2] = value
    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._R[3]
    @height.setter
    def height(self, value):
        self._R[3] = value


class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = (0, 0)

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
        self.rect = R(0, 0, 0, 0)

    @property
    def pos(self):
        return (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
    @pos.setter
    def pos(self, value):
        (self.rect.x, self.rect.y) = value

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        self.foo = "bar"

o = B()
o.pos = (50, 50)
```

which produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 52, in <module>
    o = B()
  File "main.py", line 49, in __init__
    A.__init__(self)
  File "main.py", line 37, in __init__
    Base.__init__(self)
  File "main.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.pos = (0, 0)
  File "main.py", line 45, in pos
    (self.rect.x, self.rect.y) = value
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

Comment: Off topic, but is 'class X(object)' still needed in Python3?  I thought that was only necessary in Python2 in order to get the New classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the `self.pos` setter *before* `self.rect` is set:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = (0, 0)

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
        self.rect = R(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Because `self.pos` *on `A`* is a property, trying to set `self.pos` requires `self.rect` to already be set.

move the `Base.__init__(self)` call down:

```
class A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = R(0, 0, 0, 0)
        Base.__init__(self)
```

Now `self.rect` is set by the time `Base.__init__` tries to assign a value to `self.pos`.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought that pos was being set through Base before the @property was actually in effect. Thanks for the great explanation

Answer (score 2):

i think if you change it to this

```
class A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
       self.rect = R(0, 0, 0, 0)
       Base.__init__(self)
```

it will work

the problem is that `Base.__init__` sets pos , which is a setter method of B that references `self.rect` but `self.rect` is not created until after the init call.

so to resolve the issue, simple ensure that `self.rect` exists before calling `__init__` constructor